# comments are not highlighted with numbers in derived mode of prog-mode

Tags: spacemacs, font-lock, major-mode

It seems if the major mode is derived from `prog-mode`, a comment line will not be highlighted as a comment if it contains any numbers surrounded by blank spaces.

The content of `tt-mode.el`

```
(setq tt--font-lock-keywords
        `(
          (,"//.*" . font-lock-comment-face)
         ))

;;;###autoload
(define-derived-mode tt-mode prog-mode "tt-mode"
  (setq font-lock-defaults '((tt--font-lock-keywords)))
)

(provide 'tt-mode)
```

The test file:

```
// rendered as a comment
// rendered as a comment with a123
// not rendered as a comment with a 123
```

if `prog-mode` is replaced by `nil`, the issue is gone. So I guess the cause is related to `prog-mode`.

Answer (score 2):

You probably have some other font-lock package active which highlights numbers first, which is activated when `prog-mode` is started. By default, a font-lock keyword is *not* applied if there already is some kind of highlighting in place. You can use the `OVERRIDE` flag (see the variable `font-lock-keywords` for a detailed description of this) to tell font-lock to apply your rule anyway.

Having said that, using font-lock keywords to highlight comments is not the most efficient way. Instead, if you define comment characters in the syntax table, font-lock will highlight them for you automatically.

If you want to investigate this yourself, you can use my [font-lock-studio](https://github.com/Lindydancer/font-lock-studio) to debug your font-lock keywords.